# Sankey plot labels are misaligned when rendered in a new window on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, jupyter-notebook, plotly, sankey-diagram

Using iplot will show the chart inline and is perfect (except for the resizing flexibility of a new window)

```
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

Using plot will open in a new window and has label backgrounds that are duplicated and misaligned (at all sizes and with all data quantities)

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, validate=False)
```

This issue occurs in Safari and Chrome on MacOS but not in Opera on Windows

- Different browsers - no effect
- Different OS - Good: no issue
- Changing rendering modules - no effect

---

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly 
import chart_studio
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

Get some MySQL Data in data frame, do a pivot and flatten into a dataframe here. Basically Source, Target, Count as the table results.

```
df = df4[df4.Cnt > 120]
```

Filtered to a minimum amount for the screenshot attached.

```
cat_cols=['Source', 'Target']
labelList = []
colorNumList = []
value_cols='Cnt'

for catCol in cat_cols:
labelListTemp =  list(set(df[catCol].values))
colorNumList.append(len(labelListTemp))
labelList = labelList + labelListTemp
```

Remove duplicates from labelList

```
labelList = list(dict.fromkeys(labelList))
```

Transform df into a source-target pair

```
for i in range(len(cat_cols)-1):
if i==0:
    sourceTargetDf = df[[cat_cols[i],cat_cols[i+1],value_cols]]
    sourceTargetDf.columns = ['source','target','count']
else:
    tempDf = df[[cat_cols[i],cat_cols[i+1],value_cols]]
    tempDf.columns = ['source','target','count']
    sourceTargetDf = pd.concat([sourceTargetDf,tempDf])
    sourceTargetDf = sourceTargetDf.groupby(['source','target']).agg({'count':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

add index for source-target pair

```
sourceTargetDf['sourceID'] = sourceTargetDf['source'].apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x))
sourceTargetDf['targetID'] = sourceTargetDf['target'].apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x))

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
node = dict(
    pad = 15,
    thickness = 20,
    line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
    label = labelList
),
link = dict(
    source = sourceTargetDf['sourceID'],
    target = sourceTargetDf['targetID'],
    value = sourceTargetDf['count']
))])
fig.update_layout(title_text='Test')
```

This Plotly needs importation of plotly even though there are other modules imported

```
import plotly
```

This opens a new window and has blurred labels

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, validate=False)
```

These work but are inline

```
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, validate=False)
pio.show(fig)
fig.show()
```

[Sankey with bad labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wBxV.png)